# monitor isnt fullscreen

Tags: 16.04, nvidia, display, display-resolution, vga

I have been fighting with Ubuntu 16.04, for 3 days and I don't get it, I'm using Gnome and I can't reach the 1920x1080 res.

```
xrandr: Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1024 x 768, maximum 16384 x 16384
DVI-I-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VGA-0 connected primary 1024x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
   1024x768      60.00*+
   1360x768      59.96    59.80  
   1152x864      60.00  
   800x600       72.19    60.32    56.25  
   680x384       59.96    59.80  
   640x480       59.94  
   512x384       60.00  
   400x300       72.19  
   320x240       60.05  
DVI-I-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

`lspci -v`: https://paste.ubuntu.com/23375255/

Comment: Is it a real PC or is a virtual machine?

Comment: is my real pc, i use it for programming, i have use it before on the 9.10 but on 16.04 have change alot!

Comment: I'm not competent to give you full solution. I had similar problem with an old monitor, which Ubuntu not recognize correctly. In this case the reason was not the video card. If you want I can throw you the steps of manually adding of a resolution.

Answer (score 0):

For everyone that have this problem, is solved by force xorg to load your edid, [the way that you can found your monitor edid](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=316985)

it works for me, i hope someone can use it!

hf & gl!